# Bearer authorization is not working in Karate

Tags: karate, bearer-token

I am running a Bearer authentication on Graphql server, it's working on Postman and it's not working on Karate framework.

```
    Scenario: Check authorisation
      Given text query =
      """
      config { name value }
      """
      And request { query: '#(query)' }
      And header 'Authorization' = 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
      And cookie foo = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
      When method Post
      Then status 200
      Then print error
```

**Execution Logs:**

```
16:28:03.390 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Authorization Cookie:  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJjaWctcWE1LXRydC1lcGF4LmJzZ2cuY28udWsiLCJzdWIiOiI1MjY1YmNiNS03NDlmLTQyMGMtOTczOC1kYTA5ZDA0MWU5ZGYiLCJlcGF4RGF0YSI6eyJyb2xlIjoiUEFYIiwic2VjdG9yIjoiN2NlYWViZmItNTIwYS00ODVkLTgzOTItOWFjOGI4ZDQ5NTNiIn0sImlhdCI6MTY1Njg0NTg4MywiZXhwIjoxNjU2OTMyMjgzfQ.3xinKBMKvFRaLH4kRqBLSALAm6K-QqFF9jD5nTlxa3I 
16:28:03.418 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
2 > POST https://baseUrl/air-server/graphql
2 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2 > Accept: */*
2 > Connection: keep-alive
2 > 'Authorization': Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJjaWctcWE1LXRydC1lcGF4LmJzZ2cuY28udWsiLCJzdWIiOiI1MjY1YmNiNS03NDlmLTQyMGMtOTczOC1kYTA5ZDA0MWU5ZGYiLCJlcGF4RGF0YSI6eyJyb2xlIjoiUEFYIiwic2VjdG9yIjoiN2NlYWViZmItNTIwYS00ODVkLTgzOTItOWFjOGI4ZDQ5NTNiIn0sImlhdCI6MTY1Njg0NTg4MywiZXhwIjoxNjU2OTMyMjgzfQ.3xinKBMKvFRaLH4kRqBLSALAm6K-QqFF9jD5nTlxa3I
2 > 'Cookie': epax_jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJjaWctcWE1LXRydC1lcGF4LmJzZ2cuY28udWsiLCJzdWIiOiI1MjY1YmNiNS03NDlmLTQyMGMtOTczOC1kYTA5ZDA0MWU5ZGYiLCJlcGF4RGF0YSI6eyJyb2xlIjoiUEFYIiwic2VjdG9yIjoiN2NlYWViZmItNTIwYS00ODVkLTgzOTItOWFjOGI4ZDQ5NTNiIn0sImlhdCI6MTY1Njg0NTg4MywiZXhwIjoxNjU2OTMyMjgzfQ.3xinKBMKvFRaLH4kRqBLSALAm6K-QqFF9jD5nTlxa3I
2 > Cookie: epax_jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJjaWctcWE1LXRydC1lcGF4LmJzZ2cuY28udWsiLCJzdWIiOiI1MjY1YmNiNS03NDlmLTQyMGMtOTczOC1kYTA5ZDA0MWU5ZGYiLCJlcGF4RGF0YSI6eyJyb2xlIjoiUEFYIiwic2VjdG9yIjoiN2NlYWViZmItNTIwYS00ODVkLTgzOTItOWFjOGI4ZDQ5NTNiIn0sImlhdCI6MTY1Njg0NTg4MywiZXhwIjoxNjU2OTMyMjgzfQ.3xinKBMKvFRaLH4kRqBLSALAm6K-QqFF9jD5nTlxa3I
2 > Content-Length: 33
2 > Host: baseUrl
2 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/15.0.2)
2 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
{"query":"config { name value }"}

16:28:04.064 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 645
2 < 400
2 < Date: Sun, 03 Jul 2022 10:58:03 GMT
2 < Content-Type: application/json
2 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2 < Connection: keep-alive
2 < X-Powered-By: Express
2 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
{"errors":[{"message":"Context creation failed: Unauthorized","extensions":{"code":"UNAUTHENTICATED"}}]}


16:28:04.065 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/gss/users/users.feature:27
Then status 200
status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 645, url: https://baseUrl/air-server/graphql, response: 
{"errors":[{"message":"Context creation failed: Unauthorized","extensions":{"code":"UNAUTHENTICATED"}}]}

src/test/java/gss/users/users.feature:27

status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 645, url: https://baseUrl/air-server/graphql, response:
{"errors":[{"message":"Context creation failed: Unauthorized","extensions":{"code":"UNAUTHENTICATED"}}]}
```

Comment: this question has not enough info to identify the problem. or in other words, "it works for me"

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas, thanks for the response!  Basically, I am trying to generate a cookie and pass it for another URL. its working on postman, however its failing with an authorization issue. Kindly take a look at the logs.

Comment: sorry I can't help any more here. work with someone who knows the server-side if you can, search for other answers, or help others replicate this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas, sure, will check with the developer. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `headers` instead of `header` and `cookie` separately and send all `headers` at once. Sometimes Karate fails when these were sent separately.

hardcode tokens to check if its working.